# How can I apply PayTm Applicable for only Indian Customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway

How can I apply the condition that an **Indian customer** is only allowed to use **PayTm** in **Payment Gateway**? How can I set this condition?

[image]

Comment: Which paytm extension you are using? Evince Paytm?

Comment: @AthulVijayan https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Magento_Kit/tree/master/Magento_v1.x/Magento%20Plugin%20V1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating cart rule, you can add the following in your paytm extension's etc/system.xml file after let's say

```
<mode translate="label">
   <label>Select Mode</label>
   <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
   <source_model>paytm/config_source_instid2</source_model>
   <sort_order>7</sort_order>
   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
   <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</mode>


<allowspecific translate="label">
    <label>Payment from applicable countries</label>
    <frontend_type>allowspecific</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>50</sort_order>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries</source_model>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
 </allowspecific>
 <specificcountry translate="label">
    <label>Payment from Specific countries</label>
    <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>51</sort_order>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
 </specificcountry>
```

Clear your cache and in the backend you can see "Payment from applicable countries" and "Payment from Specific countries" options would appear in the paytm configuration settings. Select "specific countries" from the first box and "India" from the next box.

Comment: could you pls explain these lines,, <sort_order>7</sort_order>
   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
   <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>

Comment: @Zus - these lines manage the visibility and position of the tab/option in backend. I.e. `<show_in_default>1</show_in_default> 
<show_in_website>0</show_in_website> <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>` would mean that this tab/option is visible in your default config in admin only and can not for example be changed on store level (hence for a single store view setup this is not relevant anyway).

Comment: @zus is this solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, in my case, in the magento backend two elements appeared, I selected specific countries from the first dropdown and selected India from the list of countries in the next list box. Now when I select my billing address for India the paytm option is available and it disappears for other countries.

Comment: @AthulVijayan yes working..

Comment: @AthulVijayan could you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215022/57334